# I am trying to find a book about alien captured on earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I am trying to find a book that I read about 15 years ago. It is about an alien who was somehow captured on Earth and put in prison. One man is assigned to interview that alien and he starts a series of interviews which transforms into interesting philosophical conversation between them about advance civilizations and mind evolving in humans.

Comment: There could be a number of books that match this description. Can you think of any other details, no matter how trivial, that might help identify this book?

Comment: Is it K-Pax?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-PAX

Comment: Its not K-Pax...i dont remember any specific details :( just maybe that is written from interviewers perspective, like a journal or something, if that helps.

Comment: This actually quite reminds me of the original of "The Day The Earth Stood Still" but I am fairly sure that that's not it - or is it?